# Resizing windows snapping not working since 21.10 upgrade

Tags: 21.10

Ever since the 21.10 Upgrade, all windows no longer snap to one another as you're resizing them. They only snap to the sides of your desktop. How do I get the original functionality back? Maybe a config setting got changed, or a package was removed?

Old Window Snapping in 21.04:
[image: Window Snapping in 21.04]

Answer (score 0):

the behaviour I see is starting with two windows, size one to the left half (meta-left arrow), one to the right half (meta-right arrow) and then they are snapped together.

Perhaps you need to turn off all extensions and see if that helps

Comment: What you're describing isn't what I'm talking about. This is a problem with Ubuntu 21.10 and it exists whether you upgrade or use a fresh install. On an older version of Ubuntu, using your example, if you manually drag the right side of your lefthand window it should snap to the righthand window's left side automatically instead of overlapping 1+ pixels. This no longer happens in version 21.10, and now it's almost impossible to quickly adjust windows to pixel-perfect dimensions.

Comment: ok, I see. I don't remember that functionality. It's not in standard gnome shell, that's for sure, so it won't be in Ubuntu. You might need to look into one of the tiling extensions.

Comment: Alright, well it's definitely been the default behavior in Ubuntu for awhile. As a sanity check, I redownloaded v21.04 in a VM and added a gif of the expected behavior. It's such an obvious difference, I'm just completely baffled that nobody else seems to have noticed or has any idea what could've changed to cause this.